# How to add arrays in PHP

Tags: arrays

I want to add array like this .

```
$a1=["red","green"];
$a2=["blue","yellow"];
```

Adding 3 arrays like this

```
$main_array=[["red","green"],["blue","yellow"]];
```

I tried array merge but it do like this:

```
$main_array=["red","yellow","blue","green"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try multidimensional arrays

```
$a1=array("red","green");
$a2=array("blue","yellow");

$main_array=array($a1,$a2);
print_r($main_array);
```

Comment: HAHA LOL really :) I find myself very guilty now :D